# Points to Walls Tab 3D Scatter Plots with Matplotlib or Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot points to Walls Tab 3D Scatter Plots with `Matplotlib`, something like below.

[image]

May I know, how can the code below can be modified or if someone can share with me any good resource to achieve the aforementioned objective

```
import re, seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

data = {'th': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        'pdvalue': [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.1,1,1.1,3,1],
        'my_val': [1.2,3.2,4,5.1,1,2,5.1,1,2,4,1,3,6,6,2,3],
        'name':['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# convert unique str into unique int
order_dict = {k: i for i, k in enumerate ( df ['name'])}
df ['name_int'] = df ['name'].map ( order_dict )
data_np=df.to_numpy()

# generate data

x = data_np[:,0]
y = data_np[:,1]
z = data_np[:,2]

# axes instance
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# get colormap from seaborn
cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl", 256).as_hex())

# plot
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=40, c=data_np[:,4], marker='o', cmap=cmap, alpha=1)
ax.set_xlabel('th')
ax.set_ylabel('pdvalue')
ax.set_zlabel('my_val')

# legend
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements(), bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple example below. It will give you some hints.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data={'x':[2,3,4,5],
      'y':[4,6,3,2],
      'z':[5,12,4,7]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_np=df.to_numpy()

x = data_np[:,0]
y = data_np[:,1]
z = data_np[:,2]

z2=np.ones(shape=x.shape)*min(z)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

#scatter
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=40, marker='o',color='red', alpha=1)

#lines
for i,j,k,h in zip(x,y,z,z2):
    ax.plot([i,i],[j,j],[k,h], color='red')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extension to the suggestion made by [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064199/6446053) and by @Akroma, these two suggestion can be combine as below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create an example dataframe
data = {'th': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
'pdvalue': [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 1, 1.1, 3, 1],
'my_val': [1.2, 3.2, 4, 5.1, 1, 2, 5.1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 6, 2, 3],
'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame ( data )

# axes instance
fig = plt.figure ( figsize=(10, 6) )
ax = Axes3D ( fig, auto_add_to_figure=False )
fig.add_axes ( ax )

# find all the unique labels in the 'name' column
labels = np.unique ( df['name'])
# get palette from seaborn
palette = sns.color_palette ( "husl", len ( labels ) )

# plot
for label, color in zip ( labels, palette ):
    df1 = df[df['name'] == label]
    ax.scatter ( df1['th'], df1['pdvalue'], df1['my_val'],
    s = 40, marker = 'o', color = color, alpha = 1, label = label)

    z2 = np.ones ( shape=df1['my_val'].shape[0] ) *min ( df1['my_val'] )
    for i, j, k, h in zip ( df1 ['th'], df1 ['pdvalue'], df1 ['my_val'], z2 ):
        ax.plot ( [i, i],  [j, j],  [k, h], color = color )

ax.set_xlabel ( 'th' )
ax.set_ylabel ( 'pdvalue' )
ax.set_zlabel ( 'my_val' )

# legend
plt.legend ( bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2 )
plt.show ()
```

[image]